# Javascript Closures - Form Submit is getting triggered before I tell it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was attempt to wrap some simple logic into a javascript/jquery closure to bind a form to jQuery validate. The normal code looks like this ...

```
// attach the jquery unobtrusive validator
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#formName");

// bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation.
$("#formName").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function() {
    viewModel.Save( $("#formName" ) );
};
```

Works wonderfully. I just wanted to wrap it and make it cleaner. So I wrote this.

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.submitHandler = function(callback){
        var container = $(this);
        // attach the jquery unobtrusive validator
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(container);

        // bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation.
        $(container).data("validator").settings.submitHandler = callback(container);
        return true;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

So the inevitible goal is that I could just do this in the future.

```
$("#formName").submitHandler(function (e) {
        viewModel.Save(e);
    });
```

I know it seems silly, but I thought it was a good chance to learn more. I just recently learned about Javascript closures and wanted to try it out, and this felt like a good thing to test it on.

The problem is, if I make an HTML form and try to bind this to it, it does work like I want...but it works twice. First, the form just 'posts' when the page loads, then it does the behavior I want and expect after that.

### Edit

When I say the form 'posts', I mean that the `alert` dialog in the `Save` function fires. There does not APPEAR to be any server-post back.

Here is the form I am using to test it on.

```
<form id="_formName" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" required="required" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        Save: function ($form) {
            alert($form.attr('id'));
        }
    };

    $("#_formName").submitHandler(function (e) {
        viewModel.Save(e);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I know you're just learning, so I'm not trying to shoot you down, but... it's a `closure`, not an `enclosure`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: The way I understood it, closures are for creating functions that do not have global scope and that you pass initial parameters into, and expose a constructor-like way to put data in without exposing what you want to keep private inside of them. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Oh, I see. I typed enclosure instead of closure. My mistake. In any event, it still isn't working quite right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your problem is with this line:

```
// bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation.
$(container).data("validator").settings.submitHandler = callback(container);
```

Here you are *intending* to assign a *function reference* to the "submitHandler" property... but, what you are actually doing, is *calling the function* "callback" with a parameter "container", and assigning the *result* of that evaluated expression to the "submitHandler" property... which, I don't believe you were intending to do.

You might try this instead (keep in mind, I really don't know the specifics of your situation, i'm just going off what I can deduce):

```
// bind the submit handler to unobtrusive validation.
$(container).data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function() { callback(container); };
```